# Self-closing tags can't have content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml, mailer

I am trying to use mailer layout for my emails,
I have put `notifications_mailer.html.erb` in the layouts folder, and I have a view for the email `migration_message.html.haml`

But why would I have this internal server error 500:

> Self-closing tags can't have content

In the `notifications_mailer.html.erb` I have:

```
<div class="article-content" align="left" style="font-size: 13px;line-height: 18px;color: #444;margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 18px;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif">
   <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Isn't this the way to add yield in the mailer layout ?

Where shall debug this error ? is there a gem to test emails at browser before testing them on the real server ?

EDIT

Code for `migration_message.html.haml`

```
=content_for :title do
  Hello fan!
%p
  %span{:id => "internal-source-marker_0.12735640932997944"} We are happy to inform you about our new website, in which you can find new features. You have registered with us in our previous website, therefore we are very glad to inform you about our new one.
%p
  %span Take a look at the #{link_to 'Virtual Circuit Lab', lab_path} & check the Lab #{link_to 'Features', features_path}
  If you’ve already checked out the site, Follow our #{link_to 'Facebook page', "https://www.facebook.com/ourwebsite"} and invite a friend to do the same!
  %br/
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `migration_message.html.haml`?

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of the question, there's a gem called [Letter Opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) that does exactly what you want. When you call `deliver` on a message, it will open a browser with the message instead of sending it.

Comment: Thanks, it seem to be a useful gem, but, I got this error when I tried to use it: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
Did you get this error before ?

Comment: No. Try to put this line to `config/environments/development.rb`:  `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` and restart the app.